# different order of recipients in outlook vs Mail on iPhone

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

When I read mail on outlook, the recipients are 1,2,3 in order of names but reading the same message on Mail on the iphone , the order is switched to 3,2,1 .  The sender is using iMail in macos to send the mail. What is the true order ?